# Cross reference of Table, Figure etc

Tags: cross-referencing

Preparing APS manuscripts, it is required that when "Table, Figure" appear at the beginning of a sentence, they should appear in their full form, otherwise, in abbreviated form as "Tab., Fig.".

Using `\ref{}` one needs to decide and type the referred names by hand; on the other hand, using `\autoref{}`, which though automatically brings the referred names, it can not, as far as I know, tell whether the names appear at the beginning of a sentence or not.

So, is there an automated way to meet the above-mentioned requirement, instead of everytime inputting by hand?

Comment: `cleveref` has `\cref` and `\Cref`. The two forms usually give different capitalisation, so `\Cref` is usually used at the beginning of a sentence and `\cref` in the middle. It should be possible to modify the involved strings so that `\cref` shows "Tab." and `\Cref` "Table".

Answer (score 2):

As long as in `\nonfrenchspacing` you can fork depending on the `\spacefactor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\sfcodefork{%
  \ifnum\the\spacefactor=1000 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
\renewcommand\figureautorefname{\sfcodefork{Fig.\texorpdfstring{\null}{}}{Figure}}
\renewcommand\tableautorefname{\sfcodefork{Tab.\texorpdfstring{\null}{}}{Table}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing

\section{A section}

\begin{figure}%
\rule{1cm}{1cm}%
\caption{caption of figure.}\label{label of figure}%
\end{figure}%

\begin{table}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
left&right\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption of table.}\label{label of table}%
\end{table}%

References at beginning of sentence:
\autoref{label of figure} is referenced.
\autoref{label of table} is referennced. 

We can refer \autoref{label of figure} in the middle of a sentence.

We can refer \autoref{label of table} in the middle of a sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see this otherwise very nice solution does not give the long form at the beginning of a new paragraph. In cases like this `spacefactor` solutions would be too fragile for me and I would recommend using different commands (like `\cref` vs. `\Cref` or `\cite` vs. `\Cite`).

Answer (score 1):

Extending the [example provided by Ronald Klopp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467272/118714) I suggest implementing an `\autoref`-variant which does
check for hmode also.

As a side-effect this provides the possibility of "fooling" the test into the "full" form  by prepending `\therewashmodefalse` to `\hmodeckeckautoref`.  I *think* you can fool the test into the short form by prepending `\null`  to `\hmodeckeckautoref`.

As another side effect this might resolve some of the situations where you get the message
`! Improper \spacefactor.`

I advice to use this with care and to carefully check whether things turn out as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\makeatletter
\newif\iftherewashmode\therewashmodetrue
\newcommand\hmodeckeckautoref{\ifhmode\else\global\therewashmodefalse\fi\autoref}
\newcommand\sfcodefork{%
  \iftherewashmode\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\global\therewashmodetrue\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{%
    \ifnum\spacefactor=1000 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  }{\@secondoftwo}%
}%
\renewcommand\figureautorefname{\sfcodefork{Fig.\texorpdfstring{\null}{}}{Figure}}
\renewcommand\tableautorefname{\sfcodefork{Tab.\texorpdfstring{\null}{}}{Table}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing

\section{A section}

\begin{figure}%
\rule{1cm}{1cm}%
\caption{caption of figure.}\label{label of figure}%
\end{figure}%

\begin{table}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
left&right\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption of table.}\label{label of table}%
\end{table}%

References at beginning of sentence:
\hmodeckeckautoref{label of figure} is referenced.
\hmodeckeckautoref{label of table} is referennced. 

References at beginning of paragraph:

\hmodeckeckautoref{label of figure} is referenced.

\hmodeckeckautoref{label of table} is referennced. 

We can refer \hmodeckeckautoref{label of figure} in the middle of a sentence.

We can refer \hmodeckeckautoref{label of table} in the middle of a sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]